# Nearest value , positive or not in mysql

Tags: mysql, function, select

I wonder how can I return a value in Mysql, being positive or not. Or even if there is a function that helps me to have a return.

Example: "select value from table where value = -10;"

My response would be the nearest of -10.

I am grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ABS()` function to get the absolute value of the difference between a given value and a value from the table.  Then just order by that difference and take the top record for the "closest".  Something like this:

```
SELECT
  value,
  ABS(value - ?givenValue) AS difference
FROM
  table
ORDER BY
  difference
LIMIT
  1
```

The idea behind the `difference` being that `A - B` should be close to `0` for values which are close to the given value.  Using `ABS()` will just give you the distance from `0` for those values.  So ordering by that column should give you the records in distance from `0` on that comparison.

Comment: Thank you also for helping!

Comment: Analyzing some more, I saw that this solution really is better... Thanks David!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
From `table`
Order by abs(value+10)
Limit 0,1
```

Not the most efficient nor elegant solution, but the simplest.

Comment: Thank you also for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where value = 
coalesce((select max(id) from table where id <= -10), 
(select min(id) from table where id >= -10));
```

Yes, symcbean, it *is* less efficient than the `order by` and `top` approach. However, it works correctly when we have more than one row with the (near to) target value, while the `top` approach does not.

Comment: This response helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: This is the least efficient method I can imagine for getting the required result (approx 3 times slower than the method used by David and myself)

Comment: Hello symcbean, i understand ... but with ABS () ignores the result if the value is negative .. Would not that be a problem?